# SQL INSERT INTO with subquery and value

Tags: sql, sql-insert

Is there a way I can use a combination of hard values and a subquery to insert into a table with one command?

For example:

```
INSERT INTO suppliers (supplier_id, supplier_name, supplier_type)
SELECT account_no, name
FROM customers
WHERE city = 'San Diego';
```

I need supplier_type to be 3. So can I do the following for the second line?

```
SELECT account_no, name, supplier_type = 3
```

**supplier_type is not in the customers table**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just add it with your `SELECT` fields.

```
INSERT INTO suppliers (supplier_id, supplier_name, supplier_type)
SELECT account_no, name, 3 AS supplier_type
FROM customers
WHERE city = 'San Diego';
```

Answer (score 4):

Even simpler, just fill in the field with the value, dont even need an AS:

```
INSERT INTO suppliers (supplier_id, supplier_name, supplier_type)
SELECT account_no, name, 3
FROM customers
WHERE city = 'San Diego';
```