# Insert value from one table into multiple entries

Tags: android, sqlite

I use this Query to get all my elements from `TABLE_LISTELEMENT` which dont have an entry in the column `COL_FK_RID`.

`db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LISTELEMENT + " WHERE " + COL_FK_RID + " = ?", new String[]{"null"});`

Now I check my second table to get the `COL_RID`

`db.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_RID + " FROM " + TABLE_ROOM + " WHERE "+ COL_RNAME + " = ?",new String[]{room}).toString();`

How do I insert the result of my second query in the `COL_FK_RID` column of my first table?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772803/sql-insert-into-with-subquery-and-value)?

Comment: have a look here on how to select from table1 row and insert into table2 row -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162/how-to-do-insert-into-a-table-records-extracted-from-another-table

Comment: I tried this:         `db.insert("listelement(fkrid) SELECT " +
                COL_RID + " AS " + COL_FK_RID + " FROM " + TABLE_ROOM + " WHERE " + COL_RNAME + " = " + room , null, null);` But the code has no effect (also no error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the perfect way. This was exactly what I need!

`db.execSQL("UPDATE listelement SET fkrid = (SELECT rid FROM room WHERE roomname = '" + roomFromEditText + "')");`

Answer (score 3):

simply use update Query to update the record of the first table but you need a where clause to update it otherwise it will update all the records of the first table.

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, ATTRIBUTE_ID + " = " + ID, null);
```

this query will update the table entry and the contentValues are the updated values, if you don't provide any WHERE clause like i have than it will update entire table.