# insert last id of column in another column table PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to insert into a column code from table calcul the last id of column code from table stock, this is my request which doesn't work.

```java
  String sql1="INSERT INTO calcul (idproduit,inventaire,consomation,date,quantite,designation,dateper,ppa,tr,net,code) "
           + "VALUES ('"+codeP+"',"+newQuant+","+0+",'"+datestock+"',"+newQuant+",'"+designation+"','"+datePer+"',"+PPA+","+TR+","+NET+",SELECT MAX(code) from stock );";
     
       stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);
```

Comment: Any errors, stacktrace? Please attach.

Comment: Please the table definitions of the two tables. Are you trying to do this after you have added a value to the `stock` table? Or independently? If you are doing this after adding a value to the stock table, are you using the same connection object for that and for this statement? Please add the relevant code.

Comment: Why are you doing that in the first place? What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve? If the `code` value was generated with a sequence, use the `lastval()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your query to include a sub-query (replace values). I am not going to duplicate answers from across the stackoverflow in here however, I would like to give you reference to a few questions that already got answers, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692319/how-can-i-insert-values-into-a-table-using-a-subquery-with-more-than-one-result) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772803/sql-insert-into-with-subquery-and-value)

In your, I would write the query as follow:

> "INSERT INTO calcul
>   (idproduit,inventaire,consomation,date,quantite,designation,dateper,ppa,tr,net,code)
>   SELECT
>   '"+codeP+"',"+newQuant+","+0+",'"+datestock+"',"+newQuant+",'"+designation+"','"+datePer+"',"+PPA+","+TR+","+NET+",MAX(code)
>   from stock;

Your query is a bit messy, so I want to put it in more generic form below

```
INSERT INTO calcul (col1, col2, ....,coln) SELECT col1, col2, ..., MAX(code) FROM stock;
```